# the bash script only reboot the router without echoing whether it is up or down

Tags: bash

```
 #!/bin/bash

ip route add 10.105.8.100 via 192.168.1.100

date
cat /home/xxx/Documents/list.txt |  while read output
do 
  ping="ping -c 3 -w 3 -q 'output'"
  if $ping | grep -E "min/avg/max/mdev" > /dev/null; then
  echo 'connection is ok'
  else
  echo "router $output is down"
   then 
  cat /home/xxx/Documents/roots.txt | while read outputs
    do
      cd /home/xxx/Documents/routers
      php rebootRouter.php "outputs" admin admin
    done

  fi
done
```

The other documents are:
lists.txt 
10.105.8.100

roots.txt
192.168.1.100

when i run the script, the result is a reboot of the router am trying to ping. It doesn't ping. 
Is there a problem with the bash script.??

Comment: Is **"Respond to ICMP Requests"** disabled on the router? That is a general option that can be set on most routers to prevent response to ping.

Comment: Post your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/ If you want to use content of a variable, use `$output` not `output`.

Comment: +David C. Rankin It is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files only contain a single line, there's no need for the while-loop, just use `read`:

```
read -r router_addr < /home/xxx/Documents/list.txt
# the grep is unnecessary, the return-code of the ping will be non-zero if the host is down
if ping -c 3 -w 3 -q "$router_addr" &> /dev/null; then
    echo "connection to $router_addr is ok"
else
    echo "router $router_addr is down"
    read -r outputs < /home/xxx/Documents/roots.txt
    cd /home/xxx/Documents/routers
    php rebootRouter.php "$outputs" admin admin
fi
```

If your files contain multiple lines, you should redirect the file from the right-side of the while-loop:

```
while read -r output; do
    ...
done < /foo/bar/baz
```

Also make sure your files contain a newline at the end, or use the following pattern in your while-loops:

```
while read -r output || [[ -n $output ]]; do
    ...
done < /foo/bar/baz
```

where `|| [[ -n $output ]]` is true even if the file doesn't end in a newline.

Note that the way you're checking for your routers status is somewhat brittle as even a single missed ping will force it to reboot (for example the checking computer returns from a sleep-state just as the script is running, the ping fails as the network is still down but the admin script succeeds as the network just comes up at that time).